# Custom field doesn't respect access rights

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have created a new field (signature image) to be shown in the My Profile section by inheriting the (res.users) module.

```
_inherit = 'res.users'
signature_image = fields.Binary()
```

Now, the user can change everything in the profile section (including the image and time zone, etc.) but can't change the new field.

The user gets a permission error message.

> You are not allowed to modify 'Users' (res.users) records.
>
> This operation is allowed for the following groups:
>
> - Administration/Access Rights

Why this new field is not following the access rules of the module and doesn't behave like the other fields?

Comment: Can you edit any other fields of `res.users`?

Comment: Yes, the user can edit any other field in My profile section

Comment: That is weird. Access right are per table in odoo. If your user can access other fields in res.users they should also be able to access the binary field. Are you testing with the same user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really seems weird, but is default behaviour for many versions now.

When adding new fields to model `res.users` you have to add those fields to a special attribute of the class behind it.

You can find examples in modules `hr` or `sale_stock`.

For Odoo 14 or some earlier versions you have to override the class' `__init__` and add your fields to the special attribute(s), [like this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7bea5890d5095abcfc8e2b6081baecfd3e9d5ec6/addons/sale_stock/models/res_users.py#L7-L33)

```py
class Users(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['res.users']

    property_warehouse_id = fields.Many2one('stock.warehouse', string='Default Warehouse', company_dependent=True, check_company=True)

    def __init__(self, pool, cr):
        """ Override of __init__ to add access rights.
            Access rights are disabled by default, but allowed
            on some specific fields defined in self.SELF_{READ/WRITE}ABLE_FIELDS.
        """

        sale_stock_writeable_fields = [
            'property_warehouse_id',
        ]

        init_res = super().__init__(pool, cr)
        # duplicate list to avoid modifying the original reference
        type(self).SELF_READABLE_FIELDS = type(self).SELF_READABLE_FIELDS + sale_stock_writeable_fields
        type(self).SELF_WRITEABLE_FIELDS = type(self).SELF_WRITEABLE_FIELDS + sale_stock_writeable_fields
        return init_res
```

In Odoo 15 everything was changed to python properties. But you can find new examples on the same modules, [like this](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/eb1adbd6af4b01a8b3b5b16dbf2d6c32eec852e6/addons/sale_stock/models/res_users.py#L7-L25):

```py
class Users(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['res.users']

    property_warehouse_id = fields.Many2one('stock.warehouse', string='Default Warehouse', company_dependent=True, check_company=True)

    @property
    def SELF_READABLE_FIELDS(self):
        return super().SELF_READABLE_FIELDS + ['property_warehouse_id']

    @property
    def SELF_WRITEABLE_FIELDS(self):
        return super().SELF_WRITEABLE_FIELDS + ['property_warehouse_id']
```

Comment: I was not aware of that. Do you have to do this with every new field you add? Strange that I somehow never faced an issue like this.  +1 anyways

Comment: You have to do that on model `res.users`. IIRC that's the only model with this kind of access restriction. But there are some others whose access rights are dependend to their related documents like `ir.attachment` or `mail.message`.